# Android. Как отобразить длинный текст в тулбаре

Tags: java, android

В приложении возникла задача. Иногда нужно отобразить длинные тайтлы. Как мне это сделать? Например, в приложении ВКонтакте есть тема с плавающим текстом, наподобие бегущей строки, но нигде не могу найти таких кастомных элементов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляем в наш `Toolbar` `TextView`:

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="Однажды моя девушка попросила меня вынести мусор, когда я играл в доту. Знаете чем это закончилось?"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Этот `TextView` будет нам вместо основного, поэтому присваиваем титулу `Toolbar`а пустое значение:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

Теперь находим наш новый титул и присваиваем ему следующие параметры:

```
TextView name = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.name);
name.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
name.setSingleLine(true);
name.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1); // '-1' for infinite
name.setSelected(true);
```

Теперь текст будет крутиться. Стоит отметить, что в `.xml` это сделать правильным образом не получится, потому что `android:singleLine="true"`, покажет Вам, что этот метод `deprecated`, а использование методов `android:maxLines="1"` и `android:lines="1"` не даст вам ожидаемого результата.

Comment: спасибо большое! Помогло